# JavaScript Date One Month Ago W/ Range Verification

Tags: javascript, date, subtraction

I'm trying to find the date one month ago from a specific date. But facing a strange problem.

```
var d = new Date(2009, 1, 25);
var dt = d.getDate();
var m = d.getMonth() - 1;  
var y = d.getFullYear();

if(m === 0) { 
    m = 12;
    y -= 1;
}

var numDays = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();

if(d.getDate() > numDays) {
    dt = 0;
}
console.log(y, m, dt); // 2008 12 25
var sd = new Date(y, m, dt);
console.log(sd.toString()); // Sun Jan 25 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

While the first console is printing: `2008 12 25` properly, but the second log shows: `Sun Jan 25 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`. How is this possible?

**Addition: More Detailed Question**

I'm not concerned about the formatting. I'm surprised why a different date object is created while I'm creating the date with the same variables I'm printing just above.

Comment: You are printing using different 'parameters' here - `console.log(y, m, dt);` vs `console.log(sd.toString());`, hence you are getitng different output. Second one is using native `.toString()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript date starts from 0.
0 => JAN, 1 => Feb ... 11 => DEC

In your case. U set month to 12. As a result when u create a date object, 12 exceeds 11(DEC) and javascript increment 1 more month which results in 2009 JAN 25.

```
 var sd = new Date(2008, 12, 25);// is equal to Date(2009, 0, 25);
```

Change ur logic a bit as follows:

```
 var d = new Date(2009, 1, 25);
 var dt = d.getDate();
 var m = d.getMonth() - 1;  
 var y = d.getFullYear();

 if(m === 0) { 
     m = 11;
     y -= 1;
 }

 var numDays = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();

 if(d.getDate() > numDays) {
     dt = 0;
 }
 console.log(y, m, dt); // 2008 12 25
 var sd = new Date(y, m, dt);
 console.log(sd.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

The best way to add a mounth to a date is just like this

```
var d = new Date(2009, 1, 25); //Wed Feb 25 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0100
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1); //Wed Mar 25 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

**It shows different results because you made them like that.**

- Your `IF` statement is true, so then month (`m`) becomes 12 and year
  is minus one.
- Now Year (`y`) is 2008.
- As you create new Date object `sd`, you are passing 2008, 12 and 25.
- As months are counted from 0, then month taken is 12 (its full year
  extra and month is 0th), so you are passing another extra year like
  that.

Answer (score 0):

As AdditionMonster said.
By the way you can improve your code with the function [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)();

Like this:

```
  var d = new Date(2009, 1, 25);
  var dt = d.getDate();
  var m = d.getMonth();  
  var y = d.getFullYear();

  var d2 = new Date(y,m,dt);
  d2.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 2);
  console.log(d2);
```

Answer (score -3):

While you print year, month and date in console, it will print as **2008** **12** **25** as these values are extracted from Date object.
Then a new object **"sd"** is created which is a **Date** object.

*var sd = new Date(y, m, dt);*

So it will print date object toString() method and print date as *Sun Jan 25 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)*

Comment: My question was not about formatting. My concern is why is it printing different date, than the date created from the variables